# Prove that $\max(f(x),g(x)) = 0 \iff \min(-f(x), -g(x)) = 0$ ($f,g$ continuous)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. How can I prove that $$\max(f(x),g(x)) = 0 \iff  \min(-f(x), -g(x)) = 0.$$

---

I know that $\max(f) = -\min(-f)$. How can we deduce the result from this?

Comment: Try to prove it pointwise. This question has nothing to do with "functions".

Answer (score 3):

$$\max(f(x), g(x))=-\min(-f(x),-g(x))$$

Since $\max(f(x),g(x))=0$,

We have $-\min(-f(x),-g(x))=0$

and hence $\min(-f(x),-g(x))=0$.

The other direction is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: max$(f, g)$ = $\frac{f+g-|f-g|}{2}$ and min$(-f, -g)$ = $\frac{-f-g-|-f-(-g)|}{2} = \frac{-(f+g)-|(f-g)|}{2}$. Now, make equal 0.